# Bug with transitionend event not correctly removing a CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently have been learning more JavaScript as I am going to be using it a lot for an upcoming internship. The company recommended many different resources for me to look at, but a friend of mine also suggested this website:

https://javascript30.com/

I decided to give it a try and started yesterday on the first project which was a JavaScript drumkit.

So the overall project wasn't hard, but I noticed a little bug that was happening. So the project attaches a 'keydown' event listener to several different HTML elements that trigger when either ASDFGHJKJL are pressed. In addition to playing a sound, the listener also attaches a class to the element that adds a little effect to the key being pressed.

To remove the class, we attached a transitionend listener to the elements. So when the CSS property finishes the transition after the key is pressed, the class is then removed and the graphic goes back to normal in the browser.

Now if you press the keys slowly, it works perfectly fine. But I noticed that if you were to hold a key down for a second or two, it appears as though the class that gets added is never removed and the graphic is permanent. I then checked the console and noticed that the transitionend event never fires once it gets stuck like that.

Here is the code from the finished file.

```
function removeTransition(e) 
{
    if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') 
       return;
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
}

function playSound(e) 
{
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if (!audio) 
      return;

    key.classList.add('playing');
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
}
```

And this is how we attached the transitionend listener, not sure if this would have anything to do with it

```
const keys = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
```

So we put in the if loop in the removeTransition function so that it doesn't remove the class for each property that is transitioning, but I noticed that when you remove the if loop, the page works perfectly.

So I am not entirely sure what is going on with the transitionend event, and why it just stops firing entirely once it gets stuck like that. And also, why it works when the if loop is removed. Maybe it has more chances to remove the class when it loops through all of the properties? No clue. Was wondering if anyone here might know what is going on.

EDIT:

I altered the playSound function a little bit to try and get to the bottom of this.

```
function playSound(e)
{
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
    if(!audio)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(key.classList.contains("playing"))
    {
        console.log("True");
        key.classList.remove("playing");
    }
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    console.log("adding");
    key.classList.add("playing");
}
```

So I added an if statement that checks if the element already contains the "playing" class once it gets stuck. I also added a classList.remove call to try and get rid of it in that same branch. What I found was once it gets stuck, and I press the key again, it branches off into that if statement and prints the console message, but STILL will not remove the "playing" class.

Comment: Can you replicate your issue in an MCVE? I have taken some of your code and put it into a fiddle, but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmazjN

What browser are you using? I am using Chrome. Not sure if that could be it or not, but figured I'd ask.

I copied over the HTML, which includes the javascript, and the CSS. I commented out all the sound stuff, since you guys don't have the files for that. I was still able to replicate it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 causes for this *unable to remove CSS class* problem:

1. The flag to mark whether animation is played is class `playing`, which is also the key to switch on/off the animation. This setting makes the problem very complicated.
2. The flag/mark change is adding/removing class `playing`. It is a DOM operation which costs more time than necessary.

To solve this problem, it is better to store flag/mark information in memory (as a variable), and stop keyboard event listener if transition is not completed.

**Store flag/mark information in a variable:**

```
var keysUnderTransition = {
  "65": 0,
  "83": 0,
  "68": 0,
  "70": 0,
  "71": 0,
  "72": 0,
  "74": 0,
  "75": 0,
  "76": 0
};
```

As every element will have 2 transitions in one cycle. `0` means element is not in transition (no transition left), `2` means it's in the first transition (2 transitions left to complete), and `1` means it's in the last transition (1 transition left to complete).

**In function `playSound`, check and mark the flag:**

```
if (keysUnderTransition[e.keyCode]) {
  return;
}
keysUnderTransition[e.keyCode] = 2;
```

**In function `removeTransition`, revert flag/mark:**

```
  var dataKey = this.getAttribute('data-key');
  var underTransitionVal = keysUnderTransition[dataKey];
  if (underTransitionVal === 2) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      keysUnderTransition[dataKey] = 1;
    }, 50);
  } else if (underTransitionVal === 1) {
    keysUnderTransition[dataKey] = 0;
  }
```

I use `50` in the above code to change flag before the end of second transition.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/73qyofzk/1/).

Answer (score 3):

Use `.toggle()` instead of `.add()`:

```
key.classlist.toggle('playing');
```

instead of

```
key.classlist.add('playing');
```

Comment: works for me but not sure why this is happening? is .toggle() less resource-intensive?

Comment: @DannyBrown Hey , did you figure out why this happens? I tried console logging (*using `add` ; transitionend for transform not fired*) (https://imgur.com/a/RZCrPeQ). Extending transition delay to around 2 secs, does not lead to this issue. `toggling` classes does work and observed that `transitionend` is called everytime with the `transform` property too.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** Add the event handler for `transitioncancel` as well:

```js
keys.forEach(key => {
  key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition)
  key.addEventListener('transitioncancel', removeTransition)
});
```

---

In the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transitionend), it mentions that:

> the **`transitionend`** event **does not fire** in the case where a transition **is removed before completion**, such as if the transition-property is removed

Or the simple explanation is in your case the transition was **canceled** instead of **ended**, so **you would need to add the event handler for `transitioncancel` event** as well, to make that case works.

```js
keys.forEach(key => {
  key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition)
  key.addEventListener('transitioncancel', removeTransition)
});
```

Comment: logging to the console for each of the transition events though does not make this any clearer (https://imgur.com/a/RZCrPeQ). Even though cancel is called, the transition DOES end. But, the `transform` property is missing. Also, the `transitioncancel` sometimes does not even fire on holding down the key(inconsistent). It has something to do with transition delay duration too but not able to figure the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The transitionend event can be interrupted and not fired at all. This can happen if the user scrolls or does any other event with higher priority. You need to include a fallback and cancel it if the transitionend event fires.

I had similar problem with touch scrolling in a mobile app, where I was animating a slider.

So ...

```
function transitionEndHandler(...){
    //remove the class
    clearTimeout(fallback);
}

var fallback = setTimeout(function(){
    //remove the class
}, timeOfTransition);
```

If the class doesn't get removed from the transitionend, the setTimeout function will take care of it.